# Using D3 selection functions to properly align SVG in HTML layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm playing around with D3 charts.

In my `<body>` tag I have:

```
<body>
  <div id="divs" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
     <d1 style="float: left;"><big>Oil Consumption - Barrels (from 1965)</big></d1> <br><br>
     <d1 style="float: left;">BP Statistical Review of World Energy, June 2015</d1> <br><br>
     <div id="div"></div>
     <div id="div1" style="float: left;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and in my Javascript code I have:

`var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",700).attr("height",400);`

The problem is that the `d3.select("body")` appends my svg chart vertically after the last div, while what I want to do is to align horizontally the svg with the div.

How can I do that?

This is the complete Plunkr -> [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview)

> UPDATE

I've tried as suggested by @Mark but it isn't working. This is the complete Plunkr -> [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview)

```
var svg = d3.select("#divs")
                    .append("div")
                    .style("float","left")
                    .style("margin-left",400)
                    .style("width", "75%")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 700)
                    .attr("height", 400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want your `svg` to be positioned to the right of the `div` with id of div1.

First, in order for this to work, just setting `float: left` on div1 isn't enough, it needs an explicit **width** in either % or px.

Second, you'll need to make your `svg` a child of the `div` with id of divs and wrap it in a `div` that is also floated with explicit width:

```
var svg = d3.select("#divs")
  .append("div")
  .style("float","left")
  .style("width", "75%")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400);
```

> UPDATE In order for your code to work I had to modify it to:

```
var svg = d3.select("#divs")
                .append("div")
                .style("margin-left", 400)
                .style("margin-top", 50)
                .style("width", "75%")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 800)
                .attr("height", 300);
```

and the div to `<div id="div1" style="float:left; width: 25%;"></div>`

This is the result  ->  http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview

Comment: I've done as you said here -> http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview but it isn't working... if you load the 2 piecharts (first done with Google Charts, the second with D3) they always show up on top of each other....